# Selecting DIV above, but not within

Tags: jquery, selector

Having trouble with selectors/transversing. Basically, I want the popup div to open when the user hits the select. I need to use this structure due to the larger program being used, so I'm only looking for the proper selector.

HTML

```
<div class="box">
 <div class="popup"></div>
 <select></select>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('div.box select').focus(function (){
 $(this).closest('div').next().css('display','block');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select its parent then find the popup:

```
$('div.box select').focus(function (){
  $(this).parent('.box').find('.popup').css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: I'm actually using a fadeIn, but the css above was just for testing, I wanted something specific that I know will show a change.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method. It will return the previous sibling of the matched element:

```
$("div.box select").focus(function() {
    $(this).prev().css("display", "block");
});
```

**EDIT:** If your markup structure can vary and you wish to match the `popup` class, use [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) instead:

```
$("div.box select").focus(function() {
    $(this).prevAll(".popup").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: @Smileek, why pass a additional selector to `prev()`? In this instance, the `<div>` element is the previous sibling of the `<select>` element. In addition, passing a selector will not walk the previous siblings (you would need `prevAll()` to do that).

Comment: Thanks, works nicely, but I want to be sure to use the class name of the popup in the selection process in case the structure changes.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, to prevent unexpectable miracles. :) Worst thing of prev(), next(), parent() and so on is that we become hardly linked to HTML-code. Any changes of structure will make a butthurt.:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div.box select').focus(function (){
 $(this).closest('div').find('.popup').show();
});
```